# How do I share Outlook calendars in a workgroup using IIS 7 and WebDAV on Server 2003?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis-7, outlook-2007

I am trying to get work group users to share their "group calendars" on IIS7 using WebDAV. So far, I have:

- Users setup on Windows XP and Outlook 2007 with profiles on the Windows 2003 server
- The Windows 2003 server running IIS7 with WebDAV enabled and a web directory calendar setup.
- The group calendar of one user has been shared and invitations sent out to all the some users
- Invited users can see the shared calendar

My problems are;

- Other users cannot edit this shared calendar
- I would like this calendar to be editable for all users
- Can some one get access to this calendar without an invite?

I had setup in Active Directory but the company saw fit to downgrade to workgroups. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: "Am I doing this wrong?" <-- Yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best options are:

1. Use Exchange Server for this. If it's not many users look at Windows Small Business Server
2. User Google Apps or individual Google Calendar accounts. You can use many of the third party sync applications to sync down calendars from Google like gSyncIt, SyncMyCal etc

Comment: thanks jon skeet also reccomended google. a pity about the small business server. this customer is heavily vested into windows 2003 and it was hard enough getting him to pay for his license.